# How to get the name of a variable using another variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables

How to get the name of a variable using another variable?
Right now I am doing a little project named "Cube". It is a Survival Simulator. Anyway, I have encountered a problem, but if there is no way to make this possible, I will do it the long way. Anyway, here's my code (Batch)

```
:UseItem    
title Cube - Use Item    
cls    
echo Cube: Choose An Item To Use  
call %name%.bat  
echo      1. %slot1%  
echo      2. %slot2%  
echo      3. %slot3%  
echo      4. %slot4%  
echo      5. %slot5%  
echo      6. %slot6%  
echo      7. %slot7%  
echo      8. %slot8%  
echo      9. %slot9%  
set /p input=Choice:   
set SlotChosen=slot%input%  
if %%SlotChosen%%==BlueBerry goto EatBlue
```

So What I'm trying to do is since SlotChosen would be slot(input of player), for example, slot1, slot1 would be surrounded with %, that way it gets the name of the variable. (This is only a clip of the code.) I also have enabledelayexpansion in my program, too.

Comment: No I do not see delayed expansion enbaled in your program.  Regardless I think this is what you are trying to do. `set SlotChosen=!slot%input%!`. You only need one set of percent symbols to expand slotchosen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :D

Comment: You could do it this way as well, `call set SlotChosen=%%slot%input%%%`

Comment: At [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990) this management is fully explained.

Answer (score 2):

Two options for you.

One uses delayed expansion.

```
set SlotChosen=!slot%input%!
```

The other uses CALL with the SET command to get the extra phase of expansion.

```
call set SlotChosen=%%slot%input%%%
```